# Saving files to SharePoint folder from R

Tags: r, sharepoint, shiny-server

I am able to open a file from a SharePoint Folder from R running on Rshiny server. But, not able to save a file to the same folder. I get error message as shown below. I tried the solutions provided here [Saving a file to Sharepoint with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895673/saving-a-file-to-sharepoint-with-r) and here [Copying file to sharepoint library in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799268/copying-file-to-sharepoint-library-in-r) with no luck. Any suggestions?

```
df <- read.csv("http://sites.somecompany.com/sites/sitename/Documents/UserDocumentFolder/filename.csv")

write.csv(df, "http://sites.somecompany.com/sites/sitename/Documents/UserDocumentFolder/filename2.csv")

can only open URLs for readingError in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
system("curl --ntlm --user username:password --upload-file someFolder/FileToCopy.ext https://sites.somecompany.com/sites/sitename/Documents/UserDocumentFolder/FileToCopy.ext")
```

Comment: I am trying to use this method but I can't seem to get it working. Are you willing to help me out with this? Or do you have another method I could try?

Comment: Sure! Let me know how I can help.

Comment: Awesome! I asked it in a new question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569414/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-from-r). I am not sure what goes wrong, but my guess is something in the url isn't quite right. If you could have a quick look to see if you spot a mistake that would be great.

Comment: I just tested the following code and it worked:  cmd <- paste("curl --max-time 7200 --connect-timeout 7200 --ntlm --user", "username:password",  "--upload-file Book1.xlsx","teamsites.companyname.com/sites/SandBox/Documents/UserDocumentation/Test/Book1.xlsx", sep = " ")
 system(cmd)