# R script to write to Sharepoint

Tags: r, api, rest, sharepoint, powerbi

Does anyone knows how to write to Sharepoint with R script using `write.cvs` or `write.table`?

I get error - `cannot open the connection` - with my code below in PBI run R script. Is my syntax wrong or I need username/pwd?

```
write.table(dataset, file=paste("https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/companyemail/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx",format(Sys.Date(),"%y%m%d"),".csv"), sep=",", row.names=FALSE, append = FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving files to SharePoint folder from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948534/saving-files-to-sharepoint-folder-from-r)