# how to download files from a sharepoint folder with R

Tags: r, curl, download, rcurl

I have some files in my company's sharepint folder. I need to use r to download all files in that folder. How can I do that with R?

I googled the question and got this link. It's about uploading the file to a sharepoint folder. 
[[Uploading files to SharePoint from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569414/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-from-r])

The code from the link is like below:

```
saveToSharePoint <- function(fileName) 
  {
   cmd <- paste("curl --max-time 7200 --connect-timeout 7200 --ntlm --user","username:password", 
              "--upload-file /home/username/FolderNameWhereTheFileToTransferExists/",fileName, 
              "teamsites.OrganizationName.com/sites/PageTitle/Documents/UserDocumentation/FolderNameWhereTheFileNeedsToBeCopied/",fileName, sep = " ")
   system(cmd)
  }

 saveToSharePoint("SomeFileName.Ext")
```

It's about uploading one specific file. But what I need is download files from sharepoint folder.

so, I modified the code to copy from sharepoint folder. I changed `--upload-file` to `--download-file`.

```
copyFromSharePoint <- function(fileName) 
      {
       cmd <- paste("curl --max-time 7200 --connect-timeout 7200 --ntlm --user","username:password", 
                  "--download-file teamsites.OrganizationName.com/sites/PageTitle/Documents/FolderNameWhereTheFileToTransferExists/",fileName, 
                  "home/username/UserDocumentation/FolderNameWhereTheFileNeedsToBeCopied/",fileName, sep = " ")
       system(cmd)
      }

copyFromSharePoint("SomeFileName.Ext")
```

However, that does not seem to work. Error message below:

```
curl: option --download-file: is unknown
```

Does anyone know how I can do it with R?

In addition, what if I need to download all files in the folder, not one specific file.Does anyone know how I can do it with R?

Comment: I'm guessing you should be using `sep =""` instead of  `sep=" "`, perhaps with added spaces in the text after the `fileName, ...` . You should copy the value of `cmd` to a terminal session and see if it succeeds at the system level.

Comment: I’m asking how to download, not upload.

Comment: Your question risks being closed as being too vague or broad, since we have no specifics. Appears you have not tried anything?

Comment: I just edit the question. It should be much clear now.

Comment: You should be using the man function to read the documentation on you system’s version of curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I made a simple R Package called [sharepointr](https://github.com/esbeneickhardt/sharepointr) to upload and download files from SharePoint.

The way I made the whole download/upload to sharepoint work from R was to:

1. Make a SharePoint App Registration
2. Add permissions to App Registration
3. Getting "tenant_id" and "resource_id" using cURL
4. Make get/post calls to API

It is all described in the package [Readme.md](https://github.com/esbeneickhardt/sharepointr/blob/main/README.md)

## Example

```
# Installing the package
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("esbeneickhardt/sharepointr")

# Setting parameters
client_id <- "insert_from_first_step"
client_secret <- "insert_from_first_step"
tenant_id <- "insert_from_fourth_step"
resource_id <- "insert_from_fourth_step"
site_domain <- "yourorganisation.sharepoint.com"
sharepoint_url <- "https://yourorganisation.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTestSite"

# Getting a SharePoint Token
sharepoint_token <- get_sharepoint_token(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, resource_id, site_domain)

# Getting sharepoint digest value
sharepoint_digest_value <- get_sharepoint_digest_value(sharepoint_token, sharepoint_url)

# Downloading a file
sharepoint_path <- "Shared Documents/test"
sharepoint_file_name <- "Mappe.xlsx"
out_path <- "C:/Users/User/Desktop/"
download_sharepoint_file(sharepoint_token, sharepoint_url, sharepoint_digest_value, sharepoint_path, sharepoint_file_name, out_path)
```