# Write from R directly into sharepoint WITHOUT being on local drive first

Tags: r, sharepoint

We currently have a workflow in R that is like this->

```
## Connect to database
classpath_name="A:/ojdbc8.jar"
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", classPath=classpath_name) 
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "blablablablabla", "blabla", "blabla")  

##Download table
df <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection,"select *
from Schema.table")

##Write object into sharepoint location

work_dir=sprintf('C:/Users/%s/OneDrive - MyCompany/General/location', Sys.info()[["user"]])
write_csv(df,"table.csv")
```

Generally works great.  Problem is, its taking up huge amounts of space on our personal computers.  While it is going into the sharepoint, its a sharepoint drive thats mapped to our computers.
We'd love to write directly into the sharepoint, WITHOUT being mapped on our computers and or being written to our local drives at all.

**Solutions I've seen:**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569414/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-from-r) (which has several linked questions) talks all about writing to sharepoint using cmd and curl.  Problem is, it sure seems like in every example the file exists locally and is copied to the sharepoint.

[This R package](https://github.com/esbeneickhardt/sharepointr) looks like its purpose built to write to sharepoint, that said, unless i'm oblivious, it still looks like the file exists locally first.

Also, either of those solutions would work I guess if I had a 'staging area' on my C, I moved the files, and then deleted them.   That said, I cant get either of those options to work.  I dont have permission to register an app on the sharepoint (for the sharepointR package) and when I try the cmd line I just get this and nothing happens:

[image]

Comment: temp files? https://www.jdtrat.com/blog/temporary-storage-in-r/

Comment: Deleting the file after it's been written to SharePoint would be really straightforward. The package you linked uses `httr::upload_file`, which is a wrapper for `curl::form_file`. I once implemented exactly this (for a very different back-end that didn't end up working) by switching to `curl::form_data` and manually filling the request from memory, see [here](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/650) for some more info.