# Writing Excel file to Sharepoint using R Script

Tags: r, powerbi, export, writexl

I'm fairly new to all of this but I have a really basic R script designed to export data from Power BI as an Excel file. Unfortunately right now I can only save it locally and would like to be able to save it to a Sharepoint location instead. I've tried entering the http but it does not work. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
install.packages("writexl")
library("writexl")
write_xlsx(dataset, "f:/Name/Test Folder/data_export.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hello BooksLM. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799268/copying-file-to-sharepoint-library-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895673/saving-a-file-to-sharepoint-with-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895673/saving-a-file-to-sharepoint-with-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948534/saving-files-to-sharepoint-folder-from-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569414/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-from-r). Hope those may help you.

Comment: @RicVillalba Hi, thanks, I have found all those in my googling but without an actual understanding of r script, I don't know how to put them into the code I shared. At best I tried the adjustment of the location from the second one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895673/saving-a-file-to-sharepoint-with-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it still didn't work.